# How to compare a query result with a Textbox value in jsp

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I'm creating an app, that displayes a String from a database. This String is then displayed in a textbox that cannot be edited(read only).

I now require that varible (ID passed) in the text box to be compared with a column in a SQL database table which is an identical String. Once the matching String is found I need to update other columns based on the queries.

when i use request.getParameter() method it is giving output as null.

i need it to be done purely in jsp. please help.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>  
<%@page import="java.lang.*"%>  
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>  
<%@page language="Java"%>  

<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
function move(){  
 document.getElementById('tgt1').value = document.getElementById('Allocation').value;  
 document.getElementById('Allocation').value="";  
 document.getElementById("Send").disabled=true;  
}  
function UnBlock()  
{  
    document.getElementById("tgt1").value="";  
    document.getElementById("Send").disabled=false;  
    document.getElementById("tgt2").style.display="block";  
    document.getElementById("Query_but").style.display="block";  
   }  
function UnBlock_Only(){  
    document.getElementById("Send").disabled=false;  
    document.getElementById("Query").disabled=true;  
}  
function Alloc_Insert()  
{  
    document.myform.action="Alloc_Insert.jsp";  
    document.myform.method="post";  
    document.myform.submit();  
}  
</script>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
<style type="text/css">  
body {  
    margin-top: 20px;  
    margin-left: 30px;  
}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="Alloc_Insert.jsp">  
<%  
try {  
    String sessname=(String)session.getAttribute("myusername");  
    PreparedStatement ps,ps2=null;  
    ResultSet rs=null;  
    Statement st=null;  
    Connection con=null;  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();  
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "tiger");  
    ps=con.prepareStatement("select DBID from Scope1 where specialist IS Null");  
    rs = ps.executeQuery();  
    if(rs.next())  
    {  
  %>  
<input type="text" name="Allocation" size="75" id="Allocation" value="<%=rs.getString("DBID")%>" readonly="readonly">  
<%  
}  
}  
catch(Exception e){  
out.println(e);  
}  
%>  
<a href="Alloc_Insert.jsp" value="Allocate" id="Send" name="Send" onclick="Clicked()">Allocate</a><br/>  
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>  
<table>  
<tr>  
<input type="text" id="tgt1" size="100">  
<td><input type="button"value="Query" id="Query" onClic="UnBlock()"></td>  
<td><input type="button" value="Westlaw Verification" onClick="UnBlock_Only()"></td>  
</tr><br/>  
</table><textarea name="tgt2" id="tgt2" cols="30" rows="5" style="display:none"></textarea>  
<table><tr><td><a href="Insert.jsp" style="display: none" id="Query_but" onclick="Add_Query()">Submit Query</a></td></tr></table>  
<table><tr><td><input type="text" value="" id="demo" size="75"></td></tr></table>  
</form>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

and the jsp used to compare the data is as below

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>  
<%@page import="java.lang.String"%>  

<html>  
    <head>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
<%   
     try{  
            ResultSet rs=null;  
            String Add=request.getParameter("Allocation.text");  
            String user=(String) session.getAttribute("myusername");  
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();  
            java.sql.Timestamp t= new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","tiger");  
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Update Scope1 SET ALLOCATED=?, SPECIALIST=? WHERE DBID='"+Add+"'");  
            ps.setTimestamp(1, t);  
            ps.setString(2, user);  
            /*ps.setString(3, Add_U);*/  
            ps.executeUpdate();  
            out.println(user);  
            out.println(con);  
            out.println(t);  
            out.println(Add);  
            con.commit();  
             }  
        catch(Exception e)  
                       {  
            out.println(e);  
                       }  
%>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

please help me with this at the earliest.

Thank You

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to get the string into a textbox (which i was able to but it only displays in textbox similar to how it displays in a html table), i want this textbox value for comparing a column in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you are getting null for this statement

```
String Add=request.getParameter("Allocation.text");
```

If so change to the following and try.

```
 String Add=request.getParameter("Allocation"); 

<input type="text" name="Allocation" size="75" 
id="Allocation" value="<%=rs.getString("DBID")%>" 
readonly="readonly">
```

Regards

**Edit 1**

This line of code makes value of `Allocation` to `null`. Are you calling `move()` javascript function anywhere? `document.getElementById('Allocation').value="";`

If so you should get the value from `tgt1` because you are assigning `Allocation` value to `tgt1` in this statement

```
    document.getElementById('tgt1').value = 
document.getElementById('Allocation').value;
```

**Edit 3**

if you want to navigate to your second page by clicking hyperlink, you could try as following

```
<a href="Alloc_Insert.jsp?val=<%=rs.getString("DBID")%>" />
```

and in your second jsp

```
request.getParameter("val").
```

Comment: Hi Polappan, i'm getting null even for this also.

Comment: though i've disabled the move() it is not working i.e. still pulling null value. i want the text box to get the value assigned. i think it is jus t displaying (as it does in a html table). could you please let me know how do i do it?

Comment: @Rakesh 1) Are you sure that you are having records from this sql statement? `select DBID from Scope1 where specialist IS Null` 2) How are you navigating from your first jsp page to `Alloc_Insert.jsp`? Because you have `Alloc_Insert()` javascript function and this line of code as well `<form name="myform" method="post" action="Alloc_Insert.jsp">`. Regards

Comment: @Rakesh I have updated my answer. Change to <input type="Submit" rather than button and try navigating to Alloc_Insert.jsp by clicking the button. Regards

Comment: 1) yes it is showing the records from database. 2) i am using a hyperlink to navigate from first to second jsp. 3)Alloc_Insert() was used because i've to use multiple submit buttons here in my page. however i disabled it and still it is showing null.

Comment: `<input type="Submit" value="Westlaw Verification" onclick="UnBlock_Only()"></input>` I changed to `Submit` and executed your code, I could see value of `Allocation` Regards

Comment: yes brother, the text is moving fine but the problem here i'm facing is that the text is not getting retrieved, i.e. the text in the textbox is only getting displayed in it , but it is not getting assigned to it. i want the text to be assigned rather than just displaying it.

Comment: @Rakesh Are you still getting null for request.getParameter() value? Could you more specific as what is not getting assigned? Regards

Comment: here actually the value is getting displayed in the textbox,but, it is not getting assigned. to be more specific the value if we use <tr> tag it is displayed in a table instead of it we used <input type=textbox> so what i want to do is not only display the textbox result, but also use the text from it. could you please provide your gmail or yahoo id so that we can chat and post the final result in this page. it might be helpful to some one else. -Thanks

Comment: @Rakesh what is your gmail id?

Comment: sunnykeerthi@gmail.com and i'm online sorry to ask for your's, i asked because it is a bit urgent work. thanks